# didAuthenticate delegate not calling while signup in xmpp ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xmppframework

Hi I am working with the Xmpp Framework every thing working fine.Im working with OpenFire Server  But when I signup my didAuthenticate delegate method not called not even didNotAuthenticate called. And also not showing as online user.I just follow the iphonexmpp demo of robbiehanson's But i don't know where I'm missing. Please anybody help me.

Comment: @bitto are you connected with your server?

Comment: yes registration also successfull and showing in openfire server also

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are able to connect, once you are connected you need to trigger the authentication like this on the **XMPP didConnect delegate method**:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream*)sender
{
    self.isXmppConnected = YES;

    NSError* error = nil;
    [self.xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"yourJIDpassword" error:&error];

}
```

After that you will get a call at your didAuthenticate or didNotAuthenticate methods

Comment: Thanks for the replay but in my case i am generating new password for every time app login for that i using rest Kit for changing my password it is working fine because same thing working at Android End. thats why  didAuthenticate not being called so if you know any thing else please let me know.

Comment: Why are you generating a new password every time? Won't suit you the anonymous login if what you want is to have like a temp user?

Comment: in my case i have only one view for signup as well as signin because  my client wants like that and some of security reasons we need to generate password like otp so that otp is used as password for next time signin